# How to "Import App Service Certificate" through Azure CLI (without PFX upload)

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

We are currently using Azure CLI in order to create resources dynamically from a third party application.

Everything goes well, except for importing an app certificate for our dynamically created app service.

We do have an "App Service Certificate", and through the portal we can import it without any problem.

But how can we do this through Azure CLI **WITHOUT** having to download/upload a `.PFX` file?

Is there some command like the following pseudo-command?

```
az app service --add-app-service-certificate -subscriptionId MY_SUB -app-service MY_APP_SERVICE --certificate MY_APP_SERVICE_CERTIFICATE
```

Here's a screen shot of what I'm talking about:
[image]

Comment: Suppose you could use Azure Key Vault, refer to this doc.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site#store-in-azure-key-vault

Comment: @GeorgeChen I already checked out that document, but in the examples it's still with the upload of a ```.pfx``` file.

Comment: You don't want to upload .Pfx file without downloading it to your local machine ? Is it the case?

Comment: @Mason,No, I'm saying use `App Service certificate` and store it to Key Vault, please check first half of the doc.

Comment: @GeorgeChen I get that, but how can I "Import App Service Certificate" without having to download it first from the Key Vault?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is something like te CLI command:

az webapp config ssl import --resource-group MyResourceGroup --name MyWebapp --key-vault MyKeyVault --key-vault-certificate-name MyCertificateName

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/ssl?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_ssl_import

Comment: @GHN I couldn't get that to work, my guess is that it doesn't work across different resource groups. The error was a little confusing but seemed to indicate the cert couldn't be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are looking for a way to upload and bind the certificate to your azure web app without using Azure portal(By Power shell program).

you can simply use below CLI command as suggested by George Chen:

```
thumbprint=$(az webapp config ssl upload --certificate-file $pfxPath \
--certificate-password $pfxPassword --name $webappname --resource-group $resourceGroup \
--query thumbprint --output tsv)

# Binds the uploaded SSL certificate to the web app.
az webapp config ssl bind --certificate-thumbprint $thumbprint --ssl-type SNI \
--name $webappname --resource-group $resourceGroup
```

You can read about the command in detail in below doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/ssl?view=azure-cli-latest

Please be informed that Certificate files needs to be present at physical location for achieving the result as the command mentioned below

```
**--certificate-file $pfxPath**
```

It takes the path of the file. SO to answer your question " But how can we do this through Azure CLI WITHOUT having to download/upload a .PFX file? " Without downloading the cert file in local , it is not possible.

But you can simply use Azure CLI command to import it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is possible to import the SSL certicate directly from the keyvault without downloading and uploading it using the latest version of the Azure CLI: az webapp config ssl import ...  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/ssl?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_ssl_import

Answer (score 2):

Without the private link certificate sync\renew certificate wont happen.

import azure App service certificate is not yet supported via cli and POS.

I had a ticket raised with MS support, unfortunately there is no cmdlet to achieve this.

I have created a feature request for the same please do [vote](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/cab7e810-ac5b-ee11-a81c-000d3adb7ffd).

Comment: Voted. In the meantime, I was able to create a hack to achieve this by doing a POST to Azure's private API with the same payload the Azure UI uses for the "Import Certificate from Key Vault" function.

Comment: @Lavamantis could you please share the API here.

Comment: OK, see super ugly hack below. I know it works as of today, but since it's a private API, Microsoft could change it at any time.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS A HACK AND NOT SUITABLE FOR PRODUCTION

This answer appears by request and is for emergency use only, which it was for us. This will copy certs from one app service to another. It only works for certs that are in the Azure key vault. It unfortunately does NOT work for "App Service Managed Certificates" - it doesn't appear like you can copy those.

You need these things:

1. Source cert's key vault id
2. Source cert's key vault secret name
3. Destination resource group
4. Destination app
5. The Bearer token of a logged in user in the Azure web UI. You can get this from devtools when you view the source certs page - it's a very long alphanumeric string. This key expires pretty quickly, so you'll likely have to get a new one a couple times if you're copying many certs.

Build a JSON payload that looks like this (this function is Javascript)

```js
function buildCertImportPayload(subscriptionId, destResourceGroup, destApp, sourceKeyVaultId, sourceKeyVaultSecretName, destNewCertName) {
    let requestName = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1)); // or any random GUID
    return {
        "requests": [
            {
                "content": {
                    "location": "East US",
                    "properties": {
                        "ServerFarmId": "/subscriptions/" + subscriptionId + "/resourceGroups/" + destResourceGroup + "/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/" + destApp,
                        "keyVaultId": sourceKeyVaultId,
                        "keyVaultSecretName": sourceKeyVaultSecretName,
                        "hostingEnvironmentProfile": {
                            "id": "/subscriptions/" + subscriptionId + "/resourceGroups/" + destResourceGroup + "/providers/Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/" + destApp,
                            "name": destApp,
                            "type": "Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "httpMethod": "PUT",
                "name": requestName,
                "requestHeaderDetails": {
                    "commandName": "WebsitesExtension.importCertificateFromKeyVault"
                },
                "url": "/subscriptions/" + subscriptionId + "/resourceGroups/" + destResourceGroup + "/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/" + destNewCertName + "?api-version=2022-03-01"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And POST it to `https://management.azure.com/batch?api-version=2020-06-01` with two headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {the bearer token from your requests while logged into the Azure UI with an account with sufficient permissions - its a very long alphanumeric string}
```